# Adding 300 options to select breaks css layout in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, html-rendering

Adding 300 options to select breaks css layout in Google Chrome is working fine in IE and Firefox. When removing the last option than layout is fine again. Don't have a clue what could cause this. Anyone has an idea? Thanks

Here you have the code snippet, set the last option in  and than the layout is as expected.

```html
<style>
  .tekst {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Actual:</b>
      <select class="tekst" name="cboUsers" id="users" onchange="verzend(this.form);" style="width: 200px">
        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 0</option>

        <option value="61">Name 0</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 1</option>

        <option value="1110">Name 1</option>

        <option value="969">Name 2</option>

        <option value="804">Name 3</option>

        <option value="789">Name 4</option>

        <option value="706">Name 5</option>

        <option value="482">Name 6</option>

        <option value="493">Name 7</option>

        <option value="502">Name 8</option>

        <option value="537">Name 9</option>

        <option value="555">Name 10</option>

        <option value="800">Name 11</option>

        <option value="997">Name 12</option>

        <option value="474">Name 13</option>

        <option value="993">Name 14</option>

        <option value="722">Name 15</option>

        <option value="739">Name 16</option>

        <option value="740">Name 17</option>

        <option value="601">Name 18</option>

        <option value="961">Name 19</option>

        <option value="779">Name 20</option>

        <option value="543">Name 21</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 22</option>

        <option value="602">Name 22</option>

        <option value="308">Name 23</option>

        <option value="309">Name 24</option>

        <option value="321">Name 25</option>

        <option value="801">Name 26</option>

        <option value="1004">Name 27</option>

        <option value="1077">Name 28</option>

        <option value="959">Name 29</option>

        <option value="927">Name 30</option>

        <option value="994">Name 31</option>

        <option value="302">Name 32</option>

        <option value="83">Name 33</option>

        <option value="913">Name 34</option>

        <option value="962">Name 35</option>

        <option value="1041">Name 36</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 37</option>

        <option value="841">Name 37</option>

        <option value="802">Name 38</option>

        <option value="909">Name 39</option>

        <option value="707">Name 40</option>

        <option value="719">Name 41</option>

        <option value="695">Name 42</option>

        <option value="914">Name 43</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 44</option>

        <option value="60">Name 44</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 45</option>

        <option value="62">Name 45</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 46</option>

        <option value="63">Name 46</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 47</option>

        <option value="1016">Name 47</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 48</option>

        <option value="1019">Name 48</option>

        <option value="1031">Name 49</option>

        <option value="1011">Name 50</option>

        <option value="1018">Name 51</option>

        <option value="1017">Name 52</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 53</option>

        <option value="937">Name 53</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 54</option>

        <option value="1109">Name 54</option>

        <option value="905">Name 55</option>

        <option value="137">Name 56</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 57</option>

        <option value="64">Name 57</option>

        <option value="529">Name 58</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 59</option>

        <option value="565">Name 59</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 60</option>

        <option value="65">Name 60</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 61</option>

        <option value="66">Name 61</option>

        <option value="442">Name 62</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 63</option>

        <option value="1058">Name 63</option>

        <option value="918">Name 64</option>

        <option value="890">Name 65</option>

        <option value="886">Name 66</option>

        <option value="948">Name 67</option>

        <option value="911">Name 68</option>

        <option value="1105">Name 69</option>

        <option value="887">Name 70</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 71</option>

        <option value="67">Name 71</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 72</option>

        <option value="68">Name 72</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 73</option>

        <option value="69">Name 73</option>

        <option value="367">Name 74</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 75</option>

        <option value="396">Name 75</option>

        <option value="364">Name 76</option>

        <option value="70">Name 77</option>

        <option value="446">Name 78</option>

        <option value="790">Name 79</option>

        <option value="358">Name 80</option>

        <option value="472">Name 81</option>

        <option value="359">Name 82</option>

        <option value="451">Name 83</option>

        <option value="457">Name 84</option>

        <option value="467">Name 85</option>

        <option value="667">Name 86</option>

        <option value="456">Name 87</option>

        <option value="433">Name 88</option>

        <option value="735">Name 89</option>

        <option value="837">Name 90</option>

        <option value="450">Name 91</option>

        <option value="581">Name 92</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 93</option>

        <option value="71">Name 93</option>

        <option value="298">Name 94</option>

        <option value="297">Name 95</option>

        <option value="270">Name 96</option>

        <option value="369">Name 97</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 98</option>

        <option value="72">Name 98</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 99</option>

        <option value="73">Name 99</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 100</option>

        <option value="74">Name 100</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 101</option>

        <option value="593">Name 101</option>

        <option value="566">Name 102</option>

        <option value="1039">Name 103</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 104</option>

        <option value="498">Name 104</option>

        <option value="724">Name 105</option>

        <option value="512">Name 106</option>

        <option value="508">Name 107</option>

        <option value="755">Name 108</option>

        <option value="484">Name 109</option>

        <option value="497">Name 110</option>

        <option value="76">Name 111</option>

        <option value="253">Name 112</option>

        <option value="934">Name 113</option>

        <option value="923">Name 114</option>

        <option value="666">Name 115</option>

        <option value="424">Name 116</option>

        <option value="374">Name 117</option>

        <option value="612">Name 118</option>

        <option value="303">Name 119</option>

        <option value="588">Name 120</option>

        <option value="402">Name 121</option>

        <option value="919">Name 122</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 123</option>

        <option value="1005">Name 123</option>

        <option value="756">Name 124</option>

        <option value="1102">Name 125</option>

        <option value="1060">Name 126</option>

        <option value="509">Name 127</option>

        <option value="501">Name 128</option>

        <option value="840">Name 129</option>

        <option value="1040">Name 130</option>

        <option value="783">Name 131</option>

        <option value="336">Name 132</option>

        <option value="935">Name 133</option>

        <option value="312">Name 134</option>

        <option value="915">Name 135</option>

        <option value="1101">Name 136</option>

        <option value="148">Name 137</option>

        <option value="730">Name 138</option>

        <option value="924">Name 139</option>

        <option value="654">Name 140</option>

        <option value="1100">Name 141</option>

        <option value="920">Name 142</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 143</option>

        <option value="702">Name 143</option>

        <option value="246">Name 144</option>

        <option value="549">Name 145</option>

        <option value="1006">Name 146</option>

        <option value="757">Name 147</option>

        <option value="620">Name 148</option>

        <option value="681">Name 149</option>

        <option value="401">Name 150</option>

        <option value="245">Name 151</option>

        <option value="653">Name 152</option>

        <option value="403">Name 153</option>

        <option value="373">Name 154</option>

        <option value="481">Name 155</option>

        <option value="652">Name 156</option>

        <option value="619">Name 157</option>

        <option value="968">Name 158</option>

        <option value="784">Name 159</option>

        <option value="845">Name 160</option>

        <option value="427">Name 161</option>

        <option value="161">Name 162</option>

        <option value="925">Name 163</option>

        <option value="560">Name 164</option>

        <option value="872">Name 165</option>

        <option value="778">Name 166</option>

        <option value="468">Name 167</option>

        <option value="796">Name 168</option>

        <option value="624">Name 169</option>

        <option value="921">Name 170</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 171</option>

        <option value="75">Name 171</option>

        <option value="947">Name 172</option>

        <option value="936">Name 173</option>

        <option value="672">Name 174</option>

        <option value="732">Name 175</option>

        <option value="746">Name 176</option>

        <option value="1020">Name 177</option>

        <option value="899">Name 178</option>

        <option value="337">Name 179</option>

        <option value="405">Name 180</option>

        <option value="552">Name 181</option>

        <option value="330">Name 182</option>

        <option value="510">Name 183</option>

        <option value="749">Name 184</option>

        <option value="703">Name 185</option>

        <option value="973">Name 186</option>

        <option value="408">Name 187</option>

        <option value="764">Name 188</option>

        <option value="844">Name 189</option>

        <option value="776">Name 190</option>

        <option value="637">Name 191</option>

        <option value="676">Name 192</option>

        <option value="665">Name 193</option>

        <option value="926">Name 194</option>

        <option value="1036">Name 195</option>

        <option value="889">Name 196</option>

        <option value="996">Name 197</option>

        <option value="747">Name 198</option>

        <option value="710">Name 199</option>

        <option value="331">Name 200</option>

        <option value="952">Name 201</option>

        <option value="518">Name 202</option>

        <option value="513">Name 203</option>

        <option value="738">Name 204</option>

        <option value="422">Name 205</option>

        <option value="922">Name 206</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 207</option>

        <option value="1045">Name 207</option>

        <option value="77">Name 208</option>

        <option value="1095">Name 209</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 210</option>

        <option value="567">Name 210</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 211</option>

        <option value="687">Name 211</option>

        <option value="78">Name 212</option>

        <option value="258">Name 213</option>

        <option value="553">Name 214</option>

        <option value="941">Name 215</option>

        <option value="500">Name 216</option>

        <option value="313">Name 217</option>

        <option value="256">Name 218</option>

        <option value="628">Name 219</option>

        <option value="377">Name 220</option>

        <option value="663">Name 221</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 222</option>

        <option value="280">Name 222</option>

        <option value="759">Name 223</option>

        <option value="851">Name 224</option>

        <option value="514">Name 225</option>

        <option value="415">Name 226</option>

        <option value="829">Name 227</option>

        <option value="418">Name 228</option>

        <option value="728">Name 229</option>

        <option value="661">Name 230</option>

        <option value="662">Name 231</option>

        <option value="846">Name 232</option>

        <option value="449">Name 233</option>

        <option value="144">Name 234</option>

        <option value="361">Name 235</option>

        <option value="587">Name 236</option>

        <option value="281">Name 237</option>

        <option value="455">Name 238</option>

        <option value="831">Name 239</option>

        <option value="452">Name 240</option>

        <option value="492">Name 241</option>

        <option value="767">Name 242</option>

        <option value="490">Name 243</option>

        <option value="275">Name 244</option>

        <option value="648">Name 245</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 246</option>

        <option value="655">Name 246</option>

        <option value="282">Name 247</option>

        <option value="218">Name 248</option>

        <option value="255">Name 249</option>

        <option value="673">Name 250</option>

        <option value="907">Name 251</option>

        <option value="638">Name 252</option>

        <option value="627">Name 253</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 254</option>

        <option value="811">Name 254</option>

        <option value="824">Name 255</option>

        <option value="988">Name 256</option>

        <option value="812">Name 257</option>

        <option value="404">Name 258</option>

        <option value="813">Name 259</option>

        <option value="991">Name 260</option>

        <option value="810">Name 261</option>

        <option value="809">Name 262</option>

        <option value="985">Name 263</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 264</option>

        <option value="370">Name 264</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Expected:</b>
      <select class="tekst" name="cboUsers" id="users" onchange="verzend(this.form);" style="width: 200px">
        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 0</option>

        <option value="61">Name 0</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 1</option>

        <option value="1110">Name 1</option>

        <option value="969">Name 2</option>

        <option value="804">Name 3</option>

        <option value="789">Name 4</option>

        <option value="706">Name 5</option>

        <option value="482">Name 6</option>

        <option value="493">Name 7</option>

        <option value="502">Name 8</option>

        <option value="537">Name 9</option>

        <option value="555">Name 10</option>

        <option value="800">Name 11</option>

        <option value="997">Name 12</option>

        <option value="474">Name 13</option>

        <option value="993">Name 14</option>

        <option value="722">Name 15</option>

        <option value="739">Name 16</option>

        <option value="740">Name 17</option>

        <option value="601">Name 18</option>

        <option value="961">Name 19</option>

        <option value="779">Name 20</option>

        <option value="543">Name 21</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 22</option>

        <option value="602">Name 22</option>

        <option value="308">Name 23</option>

        <option value="309">Name 24</option>

        <option value="321">Name 25</option>

        <option value="801">Name 26</option>

        <option value="1004">Name 27</option>

        <option value="1077">Name 28</option>

        <option value="959">Name 29</option>

        <option value="927">Name 30</option>

        <option value="994">Name 31</option>

        <option value="302">Name 32</option>

        <option value="83">Name 33</option>

        <option value="913">Name 34</option>

        <option value="962">Name 35</option>

        <option value="1041">Name 36</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 37</option>

        <option value="841">Name 37</option>

        <option value="802">Name 38</option>

        <option value="909">Name 39</option>

        <option value="707">Name 40</option>

        <option value="719">Name 41</option>

        <option value="695">Name 42</option>

        <option value="914">Name 43</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 44</option>

        <option value="60">Name 44</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 45</option>

        <option value="62">Name 45</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 46</option>

        <option value="63">Name 46</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 47</option>

        <option value="1016">Name 47</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 48</option>

        <option value="1019">Name 48</option>

        <option value="1031">Name 49</option>

        <option value="1011">Name 50</option>

        <option value="1018">Name 51</option>

        <option value="1017">Name 52</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 53</option>

        <option value="937">Name 53</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 54</option>

        <option value="1109">Name 54</option>

        <option value="905">Name 55</option>

        <option value="137">Name 56</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 57</option>

        <option value="64">Name 57</option>

        <option value="529">Name 58</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 59</option>

        <option value="565">Name 59</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 60</option>

        <option value="65">Name 60</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 61</option>

        <option value="66">Name 61</option>

        <option value="442">Name 62</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 63</option>

        <option value="1058">Name 63</option>

        <option value="918">Name 64</option>

        <option value="890">Name 65</option>

        <option value="886">Name 66</option>

        <option value="948">Name 67</option>

        <option value="911">Name 68</option>

        <option value="1105">Name 69</option>

        <option value="887">Name 70</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 71</option>

        <option value="67">Name 71</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 72</option>

        <option value="68">Name 72</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 73</option>

        <option value="69">Name 73</option>

        <option value="367">Name 74</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 75</option>

        <option value="396">Name 75</option>

        <option value="364">Name 76</option>

        <option value="70">Name 77</option>

        <option value="446">Name 78</option>

        <option value="790">Name 79</option>

        <option value="358">Name 80</option>

        <option value="472">Name 81</option>

        <option value="359">Name 82</option>

        <option value="451">Name 83</option>

        <option value="457">Name 84</option>

        <option value="467">Name 85</option>

        <option value="667">Name 86</option>

        <option value="456">Name 87</option>

        <option value="433">Name 88</option>

        <option value="735">Name 89</option>

        <option value="837">Name 90</option>

        <option value="450">Name 91</option>

        <option value="581">Name 92</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 93</option>

        <option value="71">Name 93</option>

        <option value="298">Name 94</option>

        <option value="297">Name 95</option>

        <option value="270">Name 96</option>

        <option value="369">Name 97</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 98</option>

        <option value="72">Name 98</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 99</option>

        <option value="73">Name 99</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 100</option>

        <option value="74">Name 100</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 101</option>

        <option value="593">Name 101</option>

        <option value="566">Name 102</option>

        <option value="1039">Name 103</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 104</option>

        <option value="498">Name 104</option>

        <option value="724">Name 105</option>

        <option value="512">Name 106</option>

        <option value="508">Name 107</option>

        <option value="755">Name 108</option>

        <option value="484">Name 109</option>

        <option value="497">Name 110</option>

        <option value="76">Name 111</option>

        <option value="253">Name 112</option>

        <option value="934">Name 113</option>

        <option value="923">Name 114</option>

        <option value="666">Name 115</option>

        <option value="424">Name 116</option>

        <option value="374">Name 117</option>

        <option value="612">Name 118</option>

        <option value="303">Name 119</option>

        <option value="588">Name 120</option>

        <option value="402">Name 121</option>

        <option value="919">Name 122</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 123</option>

        <option value="1005">Name 123</option>

        <option value="756">Name 124</option>

        <option value="1102">Name 125</option>

        <option value="1060">Name 126</option>

        <option value="509">Name 127</option>

        <option value="501">Name 128</option>

        <option value="840">Name 129</option>

        <option value="1040">Name 130</option>

        <option value="783">Name 131</option>

        <option value="336">Name 132</option>

        <option value="935">Name 133</option>

        <option value="312">Name 134</option>

        <option value="915">Name 135</option>

        <option value="1101">Name 136</option>

        <option value="148">Name 137</option>

        <option value="730">Name 138</option>

        <option value="924">Name 139</option>

        <option value="654">Name 140</option>

        <option value="1100">Name 141</option>

        <option value="920">Name 142</option>

        <option style="background-color: #c71444; color: #ffffff">Location 143</option>

        <option value="702">Name 143</option>

        <option value="246">Name 144</option>

        <option value="549">Name 145</option>

        <option value="1006">Name 146</option>

        <option value="757">Name 147</option>

        <option value="620">Name 148</option>

        <option value="681">Name 149</option>

        <option value="401">Name 150</option>

        <option value="245">Name 151</option>

        <option value="653">Name 152</option>

        <option value="403">Name 153</option>

        <option value="373">Name 154</option>

        <option value="481">Name 155</option>

        <option value="652">Name 156</option>

        <option value="619">Name 157</option>

        <option value="968">Name 158</option>

        <option value="784">Name 159</option>

        <option value="845">Name 160</option>

        <option value="427">Name 161</option>

        <option value="161">Name 162</option>

        <option value="925">Name 163</option>

        <option value="560">Name 164</option>

        <option value="872">Name 165</option>

        <option value="778">Name 166</option>

        <option value="468">Name 167</option>

        <option value="796">Name 168</option>

        <option value="624">Name 169</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Show a working example so we can look into the specifics.

Comment: add codes with question

Comment: A was planning to do this, but the data is a list of names. So I can't publish that.

Comment: so? if `john doe` as option #266 breaks things, then so will `fakename266`.

Comment: I will replace the data and provide an example.

Comment: Added actual and expected in the code snippet, nice interface :-)

Comment: I have Chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.86). Could not reproduce it any more. In the code snippet expected and actual are equal.